# How to change timezones and format time in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a variable like this,

```
$Timestamp = "Tue Mar 8 15:59:00 UTC-05:00 2016";
```

How do I change its format to YYYYMM-DD HH:MM AM/PM and change the timezone from UTC to Pacific Time using PHP?

Comment: The timezone isn't UTC, it's UTC-05:00

Comment: `$Timestamp = "Tue Mar 8 15:59:00 UTC-05:00 2016";
$dto = new DateTime($Timestamp);
$dto->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
echo $dto->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Thank you!
Your code helped :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object is pretty flexible.

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$TZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2016-03-09 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $TZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php date:

```
date('Y/m/d H:i', $timestamp)
```

but your timestamp should be int:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2008');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
$Timestamp = "Tue Mar 1 15:59:00 UTC-05:00 2016";

$datetime = new DateTime($Timestamp);
$datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
$new_time = new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Apia');
$datetime->setTimezone($new_time);

//New formatted time    
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```